# Generic async trait that returns the implemented Struct

Tags: rust

I'm getting blocked on what I think it's a simple problem. I'm still learning Rust, and I want to do the following:

I want to create an async trait (using `async-trait`) that will instantiate a DB connection instance and it will return the struct that is implementing that trait.

`mongo.rs`

```rust
#[async_trait]
pub trait DB {
    async fn init<T, E>() -> Result<T, E>;
}
```

Then: `favorites.rs` (See the implementation of the `DB` trait down below)

```rust
use async_trait::async_trait;
use mongodb::Collection;
use rocket::form::FromForm;
use rocket::serde::ser::StdError;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::error::Error;
use uuid::Uuid;

pub struct FavoritesDB {
    collection: Collection<Favorite>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum FavoritesError {
    UnknownError(Box<dyn Error>),
}

// Conflicts with the one down below
// impl From<Box<dyn Error>> for FavoritesError {
//     fn from(err: Box<dyn Error>) -> FavoritesError {
//         FavoritesError::UnknownError(err)
//     }
// }

impl From<Box<dyn StdError>> for FavoritesError {
    fn from(err: Box<dyn StdError>) -> FavoritesError {
        FavoritesError::UnknownError(err)
    }
}


#[async_trait]
impl mongo::DB for FavoritesDB {
    async fn init<FavoritesDB, FavoritesError>() -> Result<FavoritesDB, FavoritesError> {
        let main_db = mongo::init::<Favorite>("Favorites").await?;
        let db = FavoritesDB {
            collection: main_db.collection,
        };
        Ok(db)
    }
}
```

There are a list of problems with this:

1)

```
error[E0574]: expected struct, variant or union type, found type parameter `FavoritesDB`
  --> src\db\favorites.rs:41:18
   |
41 |         let db = FavoritesDB {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ not a struct, variant or union type
   |
help: consider importing this struct instead
```

2. I've tried implementing `From<Box<dyn tdError>>` manually but it conflicts with what I have.

```rust
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `FavoritesError`
   --> src\db\favorites.rs:40:65
    |
40  |         let main_db = mongo::init::<Favorite>("Favorites").await?;
    |                                                                 ^ the trait `From<Box<dyn StdError>>` is not implemented for `FavoritesError`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, Box<dyn StdError>>>` for `Result<FavoritesDB, FavoritesError>`
note: required by `from_residual`
   --> C:\Users\asili\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-2021-11-15-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\core\src\ops\try_trait.rs:339:5
    |
339 |     fn from_residual(residual: R) -> Self;
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
39  |     async fn init<FavoritesDB, FavoritesError + std::convert::From<std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>>() -> Result<FavoritesDB, FavoritesError> {
    |                                               ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0282, E0574.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Just for more context, here's the DB `struct` and `impl` (Currently connecting to a local MongoDB) included in `mongo.rs`

```rust
pub struct Database<T> {
    client: mongodb::Database,
    pub collection: Collection<T>,
}

impl<T> Database<T> {
    pub async fn init() -> Result<mongodb::Database, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let mut client_options = ClientOptions::parse("mongodb://localhost:27017").await?;
        client_options.app_name = Some("My App".to_string());
        // Get a handle to the deployment.
        let client = Client::with_options(client_options)?;
        let db = client.database("rust-svelte");
        return Ok(db);
    }
}

pub async fn init<T>(collection: &str) -> Result<Database<T>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let client = Database::<T>::init().await?;
    let collection = client.collection::<T>(collection);
    let db = Database { client, collection };
    Ok(db)
}
```

I've been searching for a few days over SO and the Rust community and my Google-Rust-Fu isn't good enough to spot what's the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `init` to take 2 generic parameters: `T` and `E`.

This means that the code that calls `init` has to provide the concrete types to fill in those parameters. For example, if someone was using your library, it would be totally feasible for them to write `init::<i64, ()>()`, and your code should deal with that.

Because of that, when you define your `impl DB for FavouritesDB`, you write this:

```rust
async fn init<FavoritesDB, FavoritesError>() -> Result<FavoritesDB, FavoritesError>
```

This is no different to writing:

```rust
async fn init<T, E>() -> Result<T, E>
```

you've just given the type parameters different names that happen to match a struct that you're probably trying to use.

A better pattern might be an associated type. Instead of the caller deciding what the concrete types are (as is the case with generics), with associated types, the implementation of the trait on the type sets the type.

This is common with things like `Iterator`. `Iterator` has no generic parameters, but a single associated type `Item`. This is because it wouldn't make sense to be able to `impl Iterator<String> for MyStruct` and `impl Iterator<i64> for MyStruct` at the same time. Instead, we want to implement `Iterator` for a type once, and that implementation carries with it the definition of the types it expects.

So something like this (I've omitted the async-ness for brevity since it doesn't seem to be a factor here):

```rust
trait DB {
  type InitOk;
  type InitErr;

  fn init() -> Result<Self::InitOk, Self::InitErr>;
}

impl Db for FavouritesDB {
  type InitOk = FavouritesDB;
  type InitErr = FavouritesError;
  fn init() -> Result<Self::InitOk, Self::InitErr> {
    // now you can reference FavouritesDB the struct, rather than the generic parameter
  }
}
```

I'd also add you may want to not have the `InitOk` type, and just return `Self`, but that's up to you if you think you might want a struct to be able to create a different type.

For part 2, Rust assumes nothing (other than `Sized`) about generic parameters. If you want Rust to force a generic to have some property, you have to add a bound.

The compiler is telling you here that it can't use the `?` operator to convert automatically, because it doesn't know that your error type has a `From<Box<dyn Error>>` implementation.

If you know that every error type is going to implement that, you can add it as a bound on the associated type, like this:

```rust
trait DB {
  type InitOk;
  type InitErr: From<Box<dyn Error>>;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh shoot. I thought that I defined the types of the trait when I was implementing it. Thank you so much for taking the time to craft a detailed response!

Comment: No problem :) admittedly the case where a type parameter is declared with the same name as a struct/enum could probably do with some slightly better diagnostics

Comment: Jesus, I knew starting a project was a good thing to do. Even after reading the rust book, once you face the actual problem is the time you start learning. Read Ch17-02, Ch19-04 and this: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/returning-option-self-in-a-trait/28081, and I was finally able to have the project running. Thanks a lot!